# How do I get rid of the Material DatetimePicker time underline

Tags: html, css, angular, less

I am using Angular Material DatetimePicker, I have a problem, I am trying to remove this underline, could not find a way to do it.

here's [DEMO stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-ngx-mat-datetime-picker)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the answer here :
https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components/issues/9

This css code should do the job for you:

```
.ngx-mat-timepicker .mat-form-field-underline {
    display: none;
}
```

Also check this repo if you want to update to latest version

https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components